# Best way to implement a generic class that can hold properties of different types

Tags: c#

I am creating a class in C# that needs to store a parameter. This parameters can be of different types e.g. float, int, etc. or even classes like the [Vector3](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) class in unity.

How do I design this in C#? I have done this before in C++ using the [QVariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvariant.html) class from Qt. See the following UML diagram for explanation.

[image: UML class diagram]

So the idea is to have a Parameter class that stores one value. This value can be of all sort of types. You can use methods like ToFloat() to convert the value  to a float (if this is possible).

This can be implemented with the `System.Object` class (I think). But this isn't the best option I think. If implemented this way the performance is not that good: Performance: [Boxing and Unboxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173196.aspx)

Comment: wouldn't that just be `System.Object`? but it isn't a very good idea.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yeah the `System.Object` class acts the same (I think) Do you have better ideas?

Comment: it really depends what your input/output is.

Comment: `MyClass` defines different parameters. Other classes can change the parameters of `MyClass`. There can be multiple instances of `MyClass` each with different parameters.

Comment: i mean what are the input/outputs of the parameters. its not clear.

Comment: Sorry for the question but what do you mean by 'input/outputs' of the parameters? The naming of the class `Parameter` may be wrong since the class `Parameter` is more like a class to describe a variable setting for the class `MyClass`

Comment: what would call the conversion methods such as `ToFloat`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90891/discussion-between-faas-and-daniel-a-white).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Daniel I used a template class derived from parameter. Here is the code I used:

```
public class Parameter {

    public System.Type type { get; private set; }

    protected Parameter(System.Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public bool IsA<T>() {
        return type.Equals(typeof(T));
    }

    public T Get<T>() {
        return ((ParameterType<T>)this).val;
    }

    static public Parameter Create<T>(T defaultVal) {
        return new ParameterType<T>(defaultVal);
    }
}

class ParameterType<T> : Parameter {

    public T val { get; set; }

    public ParameterType() : base(typeof(T)) {

    }

    public ParameterType(T value) : base(typeof(T)) {
        this.val = value;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
List<Parameter> parameters = new List<Parameter>();
parameters.Add(Parameter.Create<int>(15));
parameters.Add(Parameter.Create<float>(10F));

int val1 = parameters[0].Get<int>();
float val2 = parameters[1].Get<float>();

// This will throw a InvalidCastException as intended
double val3 = parameters[0].Get<double>();
```