# Best approach to hold different classes as a property

Tags: c#

I probably don't know the correct terminology to look this up on google so I'm asking here.

Say I want to have a front end control to run different SQL queries in Winforms that allow entering the parameters which will be generated at runtime.

```
public class AnalysisQuery
{
    public string QueryName { get; set; }
    public string QueryDescription { get; set; }
    public string QuerySQL { get; set; }

    public T QueryParameters { get; set; } // <-- Not sure how to do this
}
```

and say I have 2 entirely different classes that hold the parameters for a particular query

```
public class EmployeeQueryParameters
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartingDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsMarried { get; set; }
}

public class CarQueryParameters
{
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public string CarModel { get; set; }
    public string CarMaker { get; set; }
    public bool IsDiesel { get; set; }
}
```

How do I hold these different classes in the property `QueryParameters`?

What is the best way to do this?

Ultimately I need to use either EmployeeQueryParameters or CarQueryParameters for a datasource, eg

```
someControl.DataSource = new EmployeeQueryParameters()
{
    FirstName = "",
    LastName = "",
    Occupation = "",
    StartingDate = new DateTime(2018, 10, 18),
    IsMarried = true
};
```

What I have tried so far....

1)I've looked into interfaces but this looks like it will only work if all properties are the same in each `EmployeeQueryParameters` and `CarQueryParameters` class.

2) This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32844163/best-way-to-implement-a-generic-class-that-can-hold-properties-of-different-type) shows an example to hold different types as list of parameters. It kind of works but ultimately the type must still be known at the end to retrieve the correct type, eg

```
public class AnalysisQuery
{
    public string QueryName { get; set; }
    public string QueryDescription { get; set; }
    public string QuerySQL { get; set; }
    public Parameter QueryParameters { get; set; }

    public AnalysisQuery()
    {
        QueryName = "QueryName1";
        QueryDescription = "QueryDescription1";
        QuerySQL = "QuerySQL1";
        QueryParameters = Parameter.Create<EmployeeQueryParameters>( 
                     new EmployeeQueryParameters() { FirstName = "first name" });
    }
}
```

still requires the type to be known to get the value so kind of defeats the object of using a generic parameter?

```
        var analysisQuery = new AnalysisQuery();
        EmployeeQueryParameters parameters = 
            analysisQuery.QueryParameters.Get<EmployeeQueryParameters>();
```

Comment: The classes don't have some special properties, yes? Decalre simply on a property of type `object`!

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends a lot on your UI. Do you have a form that uses AnalysisQuery as a model in which you dynamically add new key value pairs to define parameters for the query? Then I recommend using a Dictionary for QueryParameters. Do you use only a limited number of predefined types of queries, then I recommend using AnalysisQuery as your model, which then you switch based on a dropdown or radiobutton list, etc. Even more, if your UI doesn't know (or shouldn't know) the list of predefined types, then you will have to construct the UI based on the actual type and values of the object in QueryParameters, in which case you can just declare it as an object and get the information using reflection.

Bottom line, your question is too vague for a clear answer.